Splitted RUN command makes container behave differently
Docker container seems to behave differently if i split one RUN command in two RUN commands
I have a symfony app running over a docker php:8.3-fpm-alpine image.
One of the image lines install some extensions with the command
RUN pecl install apcu-5.1.23 && pecl install amqp-2.1.1 && pecl install xdebug-3.3.0

If i run symonfy server in this container everything works like a charm BUT:
Then, if i split the command above in separated lines (due to stage targeting i want to make) like
RUN pecl install apcu-5.1.23 && pecl install amqp-2.1.1 
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.3.0

Then symfony server won't work and gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Is driving me crazy bc i dont see what the difference could be so maybe im missing something important.
PS: I think it shoulndt be necessary to provide further information about Dockerfile but i will if its needed.
